# Group Theory: How do I determine if an element generates a group?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I was asked if the group  $(Z_{17} \setminus \{0\}, \cdot)$ is generated by the element $2$.

I understand the concept of generating sub-groups in group theory. If I was given a group $G$ and asked to find the subgroup in $G$ generated by $2$, I wouldn't have a problem solving it. But the question that I've been given is different. It's asking me to check if a group is generated by a particular element. How do I solve this?

Comment: Find the subgroup in $G$ generated by $2$ and then check if it coincides with $G$.

Answer (score 1):

For example, and doing arithmetic modulo $\;17\;$ all along:

$$\{\;2^n\;:\;n\in\Bbb N\;\}=\{\;1,\,2,\,4,\,8,\,-1=16,\,-2=15,\,13,\,9\;\}$$

Observe that we could have stopped in $\;-1\;$ , since

$$2^4=-1\implies 2^8=\left(2^4\right)^2=(-1)^2=1$$

Thus, $\;\text{ord}_{17}(2)=8\implies \langle 2\rangle\neq\Bbb Z_{17}^*\;$ , as $\;\left|\Bbb Z_{17}^*\right|=16\;$

Answer (score 0):

Generators of $\,\bigl(\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z)^\times$ are classes of elements coprime with $n$. If $n$ is prime, every no-zero element is coprime with $n$, hence is a generator.

Comment: @Timbuc: You're right ;o(. I was answering two questions on finite fields at the sme time and completely mmixed up in this answer. I'll change it in a moment

Answer (score 0):

The order of $Z_{17} - \{0\}$ is 16, so you just have to check that 2 has order 16 in this group as well.

In fact, we only need to check that $2^8 \not \equiv 1 \mod{17}$. Now $2^4=16 \equiv -1 \mod{17}$ so $2^8 \equiv 1 \mod{8}$ so 2 actually has order 8 so cannot possibly be a generator as their orders are different.